# Displaying the array contents by using ternary operators in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, ternary-operator

please could you explain me this fragment code?

```
arr[i] + (i < arr.Length - 1 ? ", " : "")
```

- why it's "minus 1". Even if I'll put +1 or even +5 -whatever - the result is the same. How to read this fragment '-1'?

Comment: It doesn't matter because of your `for` loop's conditions. `-1` because if array length is `5` then its last element will be `i=4`, because indexing in c# starting from `0`, in that case it doesn't matter, it will be useful if you use it for example to get elements from array.

Comment: can you show some more code above that line -- i.e. what data type is arr ? an array of what? Is it a string?

Comment: int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            ParamsMethod(arr);
        }
        public static void ParamsMethod(params int[] MyArr)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < MyArr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(MyArr[i] + (i < MyArr.Length - 1 ? "," : "")); 
            }

I understand the ternary operator, only this i < MyArr.Length - 1 ' why it's -1 it makes me confusing.

Comment: @mczaplicki As I've said before it indicates end of your array, check also my answer below.

Comment: Now that your question is answered, test your understanding. Write a similar program that takes an array of elements, say 10, 20, 30 and 40, and writes them out like that: `10, 20, 30 and 40`, using one or more conditional operators. Remember to test your program to make sure it works with zero-element, one-element, two-element arrays and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[i] + (i < arr.Length - 1 ? ", " : "")`

This code reads like this:

> Add `,`(comma) after each element of array until it is last element, in that case - add nothing.

Why `-1`? Well, actually it's `arr.Length - 1` and it points to last element of array, so that condition (`i < arr.Length - 1`) checks if you are currently in last element of your array.

If you have array of length `5`:

```
int[] arr = new [] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

your `arr.Length` is `5`, but last element, is element with index `4`:

```
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
arr[3] = 4
arr[4] = 5
```

so `arr.Length - 1` will indicate to your last element which is `5`:

```
arr[4] == arr[arr.Length - 1] //(arr.Length - 1 = 5 - 1 = 4)
```

I'm assuming your code looks something like this:

```
string joinedArray = string.Empty;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    joinedArray += arr[i] + (i < arr.Length - 1 ? ", " : "");
}
```

If you put `+1` or `+5`, you will notice that your result (if you are storing this expression somewhere, or printing) will contain `,` (comma) at the end of your result.

And something more, for that situation there is a `string.Join` method and it will give you same result:

```
string.Join(", ", arr);
```

Comment: Now I see that the comma is at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because arr.Length relates to the total length of the array and starts at 1, whereass the array itself starts from zero. So to get the last element in the array the correct code is length - 1.

The code itself is adding a comma after any element except the last, and at the last element adding an empty string instead.

Comment: Length starts at zero: an empty array.

Comment: Yes but for an array with a single element lengthwise it would be 1, whereass the index for that element would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator evaluates to something like this
`condition ? result if condition is true : result if condition is false`

So in your example `arr[i] + (i < arr.Length - 1 ? ", " : "")` prints an element of the array, followed by a comma and a space until the last element in the array, for which it does not print the comma.

The last element of the array is at the index `array.Length - 1`

Comment: "for which it does not prints the comma and the array." -> "for which it does not print the comma." ?